# Automatically Sort Sheet based on Today's Date with App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Sort a Google Spreadsheet task list based with today's date on top and future dates below. Put past dates below all future dates. Like the data shown below where =today() is January 30

```
    Date         Activity
    January 30   Run
    January 31   Bike   
    February 1   Ski
    January 1    Swim
```

I found the Google App Script Below and was able to use this to automatically sort, but am not sure how to change this to sort with today first and future dates below and then past dates below that.

```
 /**
 * Automatically sorts the 1st column (not the header row) Ascending.
 */
function onEdit(event){
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();

  var columnToSortBy = 1;
  var tableRange = "A2:T99"; // What to sort.

  if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){   
    var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
    range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy, ascending: true } );
  }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How do you consider a date as a past date? Because for January 31, January 30 is also a past date. But you've written it above 31st but 1st Jan is written below. What is the pattern here?

Comment: @ShyamKansagra order I want is first today() second today()+1 third today()+2 fourth today()+3 next anything prior to today today()-n

Comment: Try this: sort all dates normally, then split those dates in 2 parts based on today date(1 array of older dates 1 array of future dates), and write those 2 individual sets of dates in the form which you have described above.

Comment: @ShyamKansagra thanks for the reply. Can you give sample code on how to do what you are suggesting?